# i want to find uniques values from database table in asp mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

There is an problem is in code is that i want to find unique values form database table using asp.net mvc4 ORM model

```
Database2Entities2 obj2 = new Database2Entities2();
                var a = obj2.Mcqs.Distinct(x => x.cla.Equals(name));
                return View(a.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your requirement.

```
   public class McqComparer:IEqualityComparer<Mcq>
    {
      public bool Equals(Mcq obj1,mcq obj2)
      {
         return obj1.name == obj2.name;
      }

      public int GetHashCode(Mcq mcq)
      {
         return mcq.id.GetHashCode();
      }
    }
```

Now you can use distinct on the collection of entities like this:

```
var a = obj2.Mcqs.Distinct(new McqComparer());
```

'a' will contain distinct entities.

Comment: i do not understand your answer please explain in detail where i use this          public class McqComparer:IEqualityComparer<Mcq>
    {
      public bool Equals(Mcq obj1,mcq obj2)
      {
         return obj1.name == obj2.name;
      }

      public int GetHashCode(Mcq mcq)
      {
         return mcq.id.GetHashCode();
      }
    }

Comment: You can create this class anywhere in your solution, but when you query distinct values you should use the class like this : `var a = obj2.Mcqs.Distinct(new McqComparer());`